# NodeJS API connect SQL Server stopped to return any things when run at 11 times

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

I've a function like this in `app.js`, to connect SQL Server to return the recordset, but when I run this function at 11 times, it will be stopped

```
var config = require('./dbconfig');
const sql = require('mssql');

//create a get product function form the database
async function getProducts(skus, callback) {
    let pool;
    try {

        let result = null;
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(pool);
        // Construct an object of parameters, using arbitrary keys
        let skuArray = skus.split(",");
        console.log(skuArray);
        let paramsObj = skuArray.reduce((obj, val, idx) => {
            //trim val single quote
            val = val.replace(/'/g, "");
            obj[`id${idx}`] = val;

            ps.input(`id${idx}`, sql.VarChar(200));
            return obj;
        }, {});

        // Manually insert the params' arbitrary keys into the statement
        let stmt = 'select a.area, a.article, a.total_qty, b.Avg_Qty ' +
            'FROM [DB].[dbo].[Items] a join [brand].[dbo].[Sales] b on a.article = b.article ' +
            'where a.Article in (' + Object.keys(paramsObj).map((o) => {return '@'+o}).join(',') + ')';
        ps.prepare(stmt, function(err) {

            if (err) {

                let response = {"message": "failed","data": []};
                return callback(response);

            } else {
                ps.execute(paramsObj, function(err, data) {

                    let response;

                    if (err) {
                        response = {"message": "failed","data": []};
                    } else {

                        let result = data.recordset;

                        let groupedResult = result.reduce((groupedData, product) => {
                            let article = product.article;
                            if (!groupedData[article]) {
                                groupedData[article] = [];
                            }
                            groupedData[article].push(product);
                            return groupedData;
                        }, {});

                        response = {"message": "success","data": groupedResult};
                    }

                    return callback(response);

                    ps.unprepare(function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                        sql.close();
                        pool.close();
                    });
                });
            }
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } finally {
        if (pool) {
            sql.close();
            pool.close();
        }
    }
}
```

dbconfig.js

```
var config = {
    user: 'example',
    password: 'support@example.com',
    server: 'exampledb', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
    //domain:"example.com",
    database: 'example',
    options: {
        trustServerCertificate: true,
    },
    max: 20, min: 0, idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
}

//export config
module.exports = config;
```

Is this related to database connection issue? Anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Generally speaking you should choose one asynchronous pattern in NodeJS and stick with it: async/await, callbacks or Promises. Mixing patterns leads to weird and wonderful bugs such as mixing together rejections and async errors.

Comment: `ps.unprepare` is never called, so the connection is never returned to the pool. Also see what AlwaysLearning noted, due to the mixture that `finally` block could run before the prepared statement is executed.

Answer (score 0):

i've fixed

```
async function getProducts(skus, callback) {
    let pool;
    try {
        let result = null;
        pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(pool);
        // Construct an object of parameters, using arbitrary keys
        let skuArray = skus.split(",");
        console.log(skuArray);
        let paramsObj = skuArray.reduce((obj, val, idx) => {
            //trim val single quote
            val = val.replace(/'/g, "");
            obj[`id${idx}`] = val;

            ps.input(`id${idx}`, sql.VarChar(200));
            return obj;
        }, {});

        // Manually insert the params' arbitrary keys into the statement
        let stmt = 'select a.area, a.article, a.total_qty, b.Avg_Qty ' +
            'FROM [DB].[dbo].[Items] a join [brand].[dbo].[Sales] b on a.article = b.article ' +
            'where a.Article in (' + Object.keys(paramsObj).map((o) => {return '@'+o}).join(',') + ')';

        await ps.prepare(stmt);

        let data = await ps.execute(paramsObj);
        let response;
        if (data && data.recordset) {
            let result = data.recordset;
            let groupedResult = result.reduce((groupedData, product) => {
                let article = product.article;
                if (!groupedData[article]) {
                    groupedData[article] = [];
                }
                groupedData[article].push(product);
                return groupedData;
            }, {});
            response = {"message": "success","data": groupedResult};
        } else {
            response = {"message": "failed","data": []};
        }
        ps.unprepare();
        callback(response);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        let response = {"message": "failed","data": []};
        callback(response);
    } finally {
        if (pool) {
            pool.close();
        }
        sql.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: And what did you fix? It's impossible to see this in all this code.  I *strongly* suggest splitting your code into smaller methods that do one thing at a time.